# How can I add a single cell to a Google Spreadsheet using the Sheets API without using batching?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958321/how-to-insert-data-cells-to-a-google-spreadsheet-using-google-gdata-client-api) was asked but not answered two and a half years ago.

I have looked at [Google's documention](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell) on both modifying cells and adding cells using batch updates. However, I am trying to add a single cell without using the batching mechanism, and there seems to be no documented way of doing it.

Here is what I have tried. Note that the entry I am trying to add does not currently have a value, which is why the linked documentation does not allow me to "change" the contents of the cell. In particular, the `CellFeed` simply does not contain the cell I am trying to add to the value of.

```
   CellEntry otherEntryFromCellFeed = // Obtained through OAuth and then finding a sheet, a worksheet, and a cellFeed, documented above

   CellEntry cellEntry = new CellEntry(5, 10, "Value");
   cellEntry.setService(otherEntryFromCellFeed.getService());
   cellEntry.update();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Entry cannot be updated at  
com.google.gdata.data.BaseEntry.update(BaseEntry.java:635)
```

Answer (score 0):

After another hour of poking through the Javadocs for [SpreadsheetService](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService) and eventually  [GoogleService](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService#insert%28java.net.URL,%20E%29), I discovered that the `insert` method will also work for the cell feed, which uses the `cellFeedUrl` from the incomplete [Sheets doc](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_cell-based_feed).

```
   CellEntry cellEntry = new CellEntry(5, 10, "Value");
   service.insert(cellFeedUrl, cellEntry);
```